# SharePoint 2013 online document set edit property page missing column

Tags: 2013, document-set, edit-form

We are having issue with document set view all properties and edit properties page column. Basically when we click on any of the link (all properties/edit properties) is shows us only the Name field.

We have verified that all the columns that we required are not hidden and are included in the document set columns collection.

We are migrating SharePoint 2013 on-premises document library to SharePoint online and having this issue on SharePoint Online environment.

Same things works fine on SharePoint on-premises environment.

Any help on this will be highly appriciated

Comment: What do you mean by "included in the document set columns collection"? Are they included in the Content type used in Document set? If not, try to add them to content type